# Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I`m new to Compose and was trying to make my Text function go to a website, but get such an error. What is the problem?

[image: pic of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely read the Documentation.

Anyway, when you type `method()`, just move the cursor inside the parenthesis and press `Ctrl` + `P` to get to know all the possible method signatures.

For the time being, this is how you are supposed to do this

```
@Composable
fun WebViewer(){
 val context = LocalContext.current
 Text(value = "Hello", onClick = { startActivity(context, Intent(/*Your Data Here*/)) })
}
```

Comment: the same problem in itemView..How I can sovle it..val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194")
                val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
                mapIntent.resolveActivity(it.context.packageManager)?.let {
                startActivity(mapIntent) ..can you give solution

Comment: What's the error? Apparently you didn't look much into this, did you?

Answer (score 2):

try like this with context :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, URI.parse("http://www.example.com"))
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

To use context inside a composable , you can use `LocalContext.current`

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"))
LocalContext.current.startActivity(intent)
```